# How can I convert Speech Mark Output to array of JSON objects in Amazon Polly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I have managed to successfully write a Speech Mark Output to a file.
But I would like to know how to convert the output content to JSON objects so I can use them in my code.

Here's my working code that writes a Speech Mark Output to a file:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var fs = require('fs');

const Polly = new AWS.Polly({
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'us-east-1'
})

const params = {
    'Text': 'Hi, my name is John',
    'OutputFormat': 'json',
    'VoiceId': 'Kimberly',
    'SpeechMarkTypes': ['word']
}

Polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.code);
    } else if (data) {
        if (data.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
            fs.writeFile("speech.json", data.AudioStream, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
                console.log("The file was saved!");
            });
            // How can I get an array of JSON objects from data.AudioStream?
        }
    }
});
```

If I run the code, it writes a file `speech.json` which has the following content:

```
{"time":6,"type":"word","start":0,"end":2,"value":"Hi"}
{"time":587,"type":"word","start":4,"end":6,"value":"my"}
{"time":754,"type":"word","start":7,"end":11,"value":"name"}
{"time":1147,"type":"word","start":12,"end":14,"value":"is"}
{"time":1305,"type":"word","start":15,"end":19,"value":"John"}
```

How can I turn it into an array of JSON objects so I can use it in my code or send it to the client?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer:

```
Polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.code);
    } else if (data) {
        if (data.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
            const buf = Buffer.from(data.AudioStream);
            const content = buf.toString();
            const lines = content.split("\n");
            if (!lines[lines.length -1]) {
                lines.pop();
            }
            for (line of lines) {
                const obj = JSON.parse(line);
                console.log(obj);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The result:

```
{ time: 6, type: 'word', start: 0, end: 2, value: 'Hi' }
{ time: 587, type: 'word', start: 4, end: 6, value: 'my' }
{ time: 754, type: 'word', start: 7, end: 11, value: 'name' }
{ time: 1147, type: 'word', start: 12, end: 14, value: 'is' }
{ time: 1305, type: 'word', start: 15, end: 19, value: 'John' }
```